# How to draw a graphic outside the browser/document?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, npapi

A line graph is necessary for the purpose of my extension in an web game online.

[image: Line graph]

I want to do something like this: [image: Line in action]

The intention is that this graph should be OUTSIDE of the DOM/browser, because if I put this inside the game document, they will know that this line has been put into the DOM with a simple call *$("#rareLineGraph").length > 0* and they will detect it, and they should not know.

I tried it with frames, but are very uncomfortable (windows)

Some suggestions please ?. Thank you very much

Comment: Unless the Chrome Extension API has some special method for letting you do so, I doubt you can do that.

Comment: No, in Chrome extensions, definitely not. I searched all documentation but only leaves making windows with borders and buttons (awkward options for users).
In Chrome apps I can create transparent windows with *chrome.app.window.create* (properties: **alphaEnabled and AlwaysOnTop**), but these properties are only available for the version of Chrome dev (without compatibility for users)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* in principle draw outside the browser with a separate program operated via [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), but that would be quite difficult and over-complicated. That is, however, the only approach that fully corresponds to your requirements.

As a suggestion, you can hide your graph from such a simple inspection by using a random ID, or even skipping using an ID and just keeping a reference to the created element in a variable. Also, inserting your node into random places in the document structure and using absolute positioning will obfuscate it further. It will be harder (but not impossible) to detect.

Other than that, I don't think there are many ideas that can help. Chrome renderer looks only at the DOM, and **there's no API to create any kind of overlay**. DOM can be hidden from the outer document with [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) techniques, but as far as I know the shadow root element will still be visible to the page.

Comment: I had not heard of Shadow DOM, I just saw but the main element remains visible in the document. Your idea of adding the element in different places in the document or change the identifier is good, but what will happen if the programmer uses MutationObserver?.
I had heard about NPAPI plugins, you heard?, I think this is similar to what you're talking about (Native Messaging)? is equal? You've seen an example of what I'm looking of Native Messaging? Thank you very much

Comment: NPAPI is deprecated and no longer works, and Native Messaging replaces it.

Comment: Wow, did not know :). Do you have an example of my purpose about **NativeMessaging**? No know if is permitted, but I am willing to pay for the solution since I don't have knowledge of C++ Thanks.

Comment: Not interested, sorry.

Comment: @wZVanG This may be of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826657/detect-change-or-remove-existing-mutation-observer

Comment: @levi No my friend, I do not want help from MutationObservers, I know it perfectly, thanks anyway

Comment: To clarify, NPAPI does currently still work except on linux in Chrome, but Chrome has announced that it will be removed starting in April.  (http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html)